# Makefile not properly allowing header function invocation

Tags: c++, cmake

Normally I wouldn't be up here asking something trivial like this, but I simply cannot figure out what is going on here.

I'm pretty new to C++, and I am just trying to inherit methods from my header class, define them in the .cpp class, and then use them in my main method, but for some reason my code will not compile.

I am using CLion v2017.2, which made its own makefile on project creation, so I am not sure if that is causing the issue here, but I can provide it for clarity sake. Here is my code:

Note.h

```
#include <string>

class Note {
    private:
        std::string title, body;
        int id;
    public:
        Note();
        Note(int id, std::string title, std::string body);
        void displayMenu();
};
```

Note.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Note.h"

void Note::displayMenu() {
    std::cout << "Note taker deluxe" << std::endl;
}
```

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>

#include "Note.h"

int main() {
    Note n;
    n.displayMenu();
    // std::cout << "Hello world" << std::endl; this code works
}
```

Here is the error I am getting

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "Note::displayMenu()", referenced from:
      _main in main-f9b212.o
  "Note::Note()", referenced from:
      _main in main-f9b212.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Thanks in advance, and forgive me if this is a simple question, I have truly been trying to figure this out for a few days now.

EDIT: Adding correct Makefile

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.8)
project(fuck_c__)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)

set(SOURCE_FILES main.cpp Note.cpp Note.h)
add_executable(fuck_c__ ${SOURCE_FILES})
```

Comment: It seems that Note.o is not getting linked by the linker. Please post the Makefile. It's also strange that the posted Note.cpp file doesn't contain the implementations of the constructors. Where are they implemented?

Comment: I was just trying to get a baseline function working for now before I tried putting a bunch of other stuff in.

Comment: If you're using cmake, post the `CMakeLists.txt`, not the `Makefile`.

Comment: Sounds like `Note.cpp` is not part of the project. However I'm unfamiliar with CLion IDE,

Comment: Forgive me I totally added the wrong file. It is fixed

Comment: That's not a makefile.  It's a cmake file.  They are totally different; you should remove the "makefile" tag here and add a "cmake" tag.

Comment: What command did you invoke to cause the build?  Also, you only show the error messages but you need to also show the compiler command line that caused those error messages.

Comment: I am on a mac so I used g++ main.cpp, and I also tried using the run button in CLion, same error both times.

Comment: You did not use cmake? Try something like "mkdir build; cd build; cmake ..; make", assuming that you build with make. cmake will create a Makefile or some other project file to enable another system like make to run. You can select which one it should use with the -G (generator) option. This other system will then correctly call g++ for you. See also: https://cmake.org/cmake-tutorial/ I am not sure whether or how this is integrated in CLion.

Comment: I figure it out. I did not properly link cmake with homebrew, once I got that working I got the code to run after following your comment. Thank you so much!